# restrict payment for loged in customer for specific products

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods

I have a category X that containe 2 subcategory and there are many products in those catgeory that are New so when a customer is not logged in i have to disable him to pay so how to dow that and what to override exactly. I am new in magento, if anyone have an idea please help me and thanks in advance